# Django async send notifications

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have a notifications for a users when the admin add notification to user i want to display on user's home page like a facebook likes or activity feed is it possible with django ?

*models.py*

```
class Notification(BaseModel):
    created_user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=225)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=600)
    is_read = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    priority = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=NOTIFICATION_STATUS, default=LOW)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

i'm able to add a new notificiation but the notifications listing when the user refresh the page. Simply i just want to do this async like facebook like system.

Comment: lookup the messages framework https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/messages/, and to do it like facebook you would have to do via javascript/ajax requests, or wait for the user to refresh the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Channels` is the best solution for this usecase. It's websocket and truly async and that connect with your frontend and backend sync in realtime.

base.html

```
socket = new WebSocket("ws://" + window.location.host + "/notification/");
socket.onmessage = function(e) {
    notificationElement.innerHtml = e.data
}
```

models.py

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Notification)
def notification_handler(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    Group("notification").send({
        "text": "This is the new notification",
    })
```

Comment: @RajaSimon I'm late to the party but could you expand on this answer? I'm trying to implement it but am unsure of the pieces I'm missing. I'm using channels so users can chat privately with one another in a thread. What would the views need to look like in order for this to work?

Comment: @Trilla I'm not sure about your current codebase. But always think like `group` pattern.

Comment: i.e) You and your friend are talking now in chat and look at this as `group`.

Comment: In high level, it's like server have to create the group when you and your friend made some kind of connection  ( probably you need to implement database for group id and messages ). I can explain more if I understand your business logic. :)