# async messages in admin

Tags: django, asynchronous, django-admin

I created a task in the admin that is costly and should be carried out asynchronously. I would do something like

```
def costly_task(**kwargs):
    def do_task(id):
        ## do stuff, you know, that is costly
        task = ThreadTask.objects.get(pk = id)
        task.is_done = True
        task.save()
        task = ThreadTask()
    
    task.save()
    t = threading.Thread(target = do_task, args = [task.id])
    t.setDaemon(True)
    t.start()   
    return {"id": task.id}
```

With a models.py table:

```
class ThreadTask(models.Model):
    task = models.CharField(max_length = 30, blank = True, null = True)
    is_done = models.BooleanField(blank = False, default = False)
```

This works well, but I want to inform the admin of the runnig task, and also when it is finished. There is a very old (django 4.0 incompatible) package called [django-async-messages](https://github.com/codeinthehole/django-async-messages) which leverages the normal django-messages package to be used asynchronously. I googled but did not find anything of newer age ... any ideas on how to do this? Can I use djangos async processes to send out two messages:

1. when task started (that one is easy)
2. when task finished

I found something similar, but not quite what I am looking for because this would require a lot of implementation effort: [Django async send notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47392454/django-async-send-notifications)